# Xamarin - Fragments in ViewPager disposed prematurely

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a view-pager with 4 tabs and each tab housing a fragment. Each of these fragments has complex view hierarchy and stuffs. The view pager is attached to my Application's main activity and as such is being shown on app launch.

Now when a user is continuously swiping between the tabs , going out of the app and coming back again, there is an abrupt `ObjectDisposedException` crash on one of my fragment instances. What is surprising is that the fragment object is being disposed even before fragment `onDestroy`.
I am pretty sure that the fragment is not being disposed by my code explicitly. So it is definitely something done by the mono runtime (may be in response to memory pressure because it happens only after a while of usage).

I am not sure if attaching my code here would add value to whatever I have explained above (because i have done nothing fancy other than using a `view-pager` with a `fragmentpageradapter`). But I can do it if required.

Anybody facing this issue ?

Comment: Since you didn't post any code, I tested a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and 4 `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` for dozen times, I can't reproduce your issue, the view of my `Fragments` are simply which all contain just one `TextView`, my guess is that maybe one of your view contains some controls which could be disposed when you go out of your app.

Comment: My guess would be the Android OS garbage collector freeing up resources - the docs for Activity.OnDestroy() state: _There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others)..._. Also note that Google recommend that layouts should be as flat as possible - that is, as little nesting as possible (see https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html and https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies.html )

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I would have put the code. But If i have to give the complete picture to you, I have to put the code in my view pager, fragmentpageradpater and individual fragments. This would mean a lot of code. Thanks for your suggestion though